# Call Spring endpoint without content-type setted

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

What is necessary to set in method signature in Spring for a call from Postman or others without Content-Type set?

The signature is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity getHouseholdChanges (@PathVariable("id") Long id) { ... }
```

When I call in Postman without Content-Type I received 415 status.

I need from others call when I can't set content type but is same always for this method.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue with spring-boot 1.5.6.RELEASE. What version of spring-boot are you running?

Comment: Spring Version: 4.3.0.RC2 and Spring Boot Version: 1.4.0.M3

Answer (score 0):

Try do delete from method signature the

> `produces = "application/json"`

This should return a String that postman should display without throwing any error code.

Comment: Ok, surfing a little bit I've discovered that you cannot remove the accept header and obviously it has to contain the type produced by the server.
In my opinion the solution of your problem is to figure out how to set the acceptable content types in the mysterious other calls.

Comment: Why you cannot set them on those calls?

Comment: I want to make call from swagger-ui and doesn't work to set content type from annotations or I don't tried the good annotation for set content type from swagger call. And I think if have default value probably will work to call endpoint from swagger ui.